# Laravel : random error : SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

Tags: php, laravel, pdo, laravel-5

I'm getting this error randomly when using my laravel application:

> SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

If I refresh the browser, I'm not getting this error. It's really weird because it's working correctly before and after.

My database credentials are stored in .env file

**EDIT**

Here the content of my file :

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=6cYKHzpblHGfE3H0n6j2tSRjoqJsgcqd

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=gestion-inscriptions-v2
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

**EDIT 2**
And here the database.php : http://laravel.io/bin/bE95X

**EDIT 3**
Still got this error, even on other computer (working with wamp)

Thanks in advance

PS : I know there is already the same questions on SO but there is no correct answer that works for me so ...

Comment: Can you show the contents of your `config/database.php` file?

Comment: done ! :) I'm working in local

Comment: That's not your `config/database.php` file, but your `.env` file.

Comment: xD sorry it's done

Answer (score 2):

According `config/database.php` and `.env` file that You show us everything is ok.

> SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

this means that database is not selected, 
seems like have problem with existence of database,
or `DB_NAME` does not get in config `database` param.

There is some steps You've to check:

1) Check Your `config/database.php` file contents to have such content:

```
<?php

return [

    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

    'default' => 'mysql',

    'connections' => [

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql', 
            'host' => env('DB_HOST'),         
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'), 
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'), 
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'), 
            'charset' => 'utf8', 
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 
            'prefix' => '', 
            'strict' => false
        ],

        'mysql2' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql', 
            'host' => env('DB_HOST_ACADEMY'), 
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_ACADEMY'), 
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_ACADEMY'), 
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_ACADEMY'), 
            'charset' => 'utf8', 
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 
            'prefix' => '', 
            'strict' => false
        ],

        'mysql3' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql', 
            'host' => env('DB_HOST_ACADEMY'), 
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_ACADEMY_DATE'), 
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_ACADEMY'), 
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_ACADEMY'), 
            'charset' => 'utf8', 
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 
            'prefix' => '', 
            'strict' => false
        ]
    ],

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    'redis' => [
        'cluster' => false,
        'default' => [
            'host' => '127.0.0.1', 
            'port' => 6379, 
            'database' => 0
        ]
    ]
];
```

2) Check Your `.env` file exist in Your app root and it's not `.env.example`

3) Check `.env` file to have this line, if Yes so delete and copy-paste it from here (maybe spelling issue):

```
DB_DATABASE=gestion-inscriptions-v2
```

p.s. because of in Your question files are correct need more debug info, screenshot and etc. to see that problem is not with `.env` or file system (maybe `.env` file cannot be read).

Answer (score 0):

Just now i see that problem, and problem was in **not saved** *.env* file (was used VS code)